# Strange behaviour, Codeigniter Database

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Code :**

```
function foo ( $param )
{
    $this->ci->db->select (  '*'  );
    $this->ci->db->from ( $this->tableUser [ 'table' ] . ' as u' );
    $this->ci->db->where ( 'u.' . $this->tableUser [ 'column' ] [ 'id' ], $param );
    $query = $this->ci->db->get (  );
    if ( ! $query ) { throw new Exception ('Something went wrong') }
    $data = $query->unbuffered_row ('array');
    var_dump($data);

    $data [  $this->tableUser [ 'username' ]  ]
}
```

**Result of var_dump() :**

```
array(29) { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["id_user_groups"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["email"]=> string(16) "demo@example.com" 
    ["username"]=> string(7) "Demouser" 
    ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$fi0zUzFlMm9QJEV5ZVo9eQMQMYApytT1asiePbSB9y" 
    ["ip_address"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" 
    ...
    ...
} NULL
```

As you can see function foo() is working as it should be, the var_dump() result is good too, the $data is an associative array, but still on the line `$data [  $this->tableUser [ 'username' ]  ]` I am getting the following error. **Why ?**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: username
>
> Filename: User/User.php
>
> Line Number: 439

Comment: want some clarification, first trt accessing like this `$data[ 'username' ] ` and `echo $this->tableUser;` see what u get in both.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju oops :P Thanks.

Comment: its working fine?? what was the mistake??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I should have accessed `$data [  $this->tableUser [ 'username' ]  ]` as `$data [  $this->tableUser [ 'column ] [ 'username' ]  ]` a silly mistake.

Comment: To avoid eventual parsing errors, follow [CI coding style](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html) (regarding blank spaces mostly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line,

```
$data [$this->tableUser['username']]
```

with

```
$data ['username'];
```

If at all you want to use `$this->tableUser`, first `echo $this->tableUser;` and check what is coming in that.